# PHPSESSID appears in form arbitrarily

Tags: forms, php

I have a login form written in PHP and each time I start the browser and go to the respective page, the first field of the form is this:
`<input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="session_id_code" />`
If I close the window, but I don't restart the browser, this doesn't happen. Any idea what's happening and why?

Thanks!

---

Form's code:

```
<?php
if (condition) {
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<dl>
<dt>Email:</dt>
<dd><input type="text" name="useremail" /></dd>
<dt>Password:</dt>
<dd>
<input type="password" name="userpass" /></dd>
<dt class="dt-buttons"><input type="submit" name="button_login" value="Login" class="button" /></dt>
</dl>
<input type="hidden" name="formkey" id="formkey" value="224ca00155w2fcda8906e1e40af03a71" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

The form is simple HTML and is not dynamically generated.

**EDIT2:**
As I was saying, when I access the page for the first time after I started the browser, this thing happens. If I refresh the page afterwards, the hidden field doesn't show up.
Is it possible to have something to do with the SSL certificate? And if yes, why some pages/forms behave like this and some don't?

Comment: We would need the code that generates the form.

Comment: There is nothing fancy about the form. See my edit above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you've got [trans_sid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid) enabled (transparent session id). Using trans_sid can be a security issue, especially if your site links to external content, or you allow link sharing - it lets a user's session ID leak out as part of the URL, meaning the session is highly vulnerable to hijacking.

Comment: Indeed, PHP was compiled with `--enable-trans-sid`, but the thing is that I have several similar forms across, and some behave like this, while others don't. Any idea why?

Comment: Depends on which ones are doing session_start(), most likely. If there's no session active, there's no reason to embed a session ID.