# XHTML doctype validation issue with PHP sessions

Tags: php, validation, session, xhtml

When I validate my login page before logging in with credentials, the page is validates perfectly. But when I validate after starting php sessions, it gives error - error being conflict between inline and block level element. Session seems to have inserted hidden `input` element after `form` tag like shown below:

```
<form method="post" action ="log.php">
<input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="l96qs5ksgpkbpkr4sblilhqku6" />
```

How can I avoid this? Can we control where this `hidden input` element is inserted?

Comment: This isn't automatically inserted. Something in the CMS (or whatever else) you're using is inserting that. You'll have to go find where and move it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPSESSID appears in form arbitrarily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576355/phpsessid-appears-in-form-arbitrarily)

Comment: @animuson: thats what i thought too, but it seems there is compile flag you can set that makes this behavior happen. I've never come across it before in my 8 years of hardcore PHP but apparently it exists.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Never heard of it either, and I can't find any documentation that says it actually adds a whole element to the output... It only talks about URLs.

Comment: Initially the code is like this '<a href ="index.php" >Home</a>' and when the session is started, it becomes '<a href ="index.php?PHPSESSID=09ve3n4rghrtc9lg9ijhq712p3" >Home</a>'. I haven't done anything other than starting a session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in .htaccess:

```
php_value session.use_cookies 1
php_value session.use_only_cookies 1
php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
```

or in PHP:

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', false);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, what was the real issue? Would you explain?

Comment: When cookies are disabled and use_trans_sid is on, php will generate PHPSESSID. It's an automatic feature of PHP